# OpenGL GLUT window very slow, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, window, glut

## The problem

I have just now begun working with OpenGL using GLUT. The code below compiles and displays two wireframe cubes and a sphere. The problem is that when I attempt to drag or resize the window it induces a noticeable delay before  following my mouse.

This problem does not occur on my colleague's computer, same code.

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 c++ express on a Windows 7 computer.
I am a not an experienced programmer.

## The code

```
    // OpenGLHandin1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

void initView(int argc, char * argv[]){
    //init here
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //Simple buffer
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,400);
    glutCreateWindow("Handin 2");
}
void draw(){

    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Background color

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.6, 0, 0);

    glColor3f(0.8,0,0);
    glutWireCube(1.1); //Draw the cube
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-0.5, 0, -0.2);

    glColor3f(0,0.8,0);
    glutWireCube(1.1); //Draw the cube
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 1.2, 0);
    glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glutWireSphere(0.6, 20, 20); //Draw the sphere
    glPopMatrix();

    //draw here
    //glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glFlush();

}
void reshape (int w, int h){
    glViewport(0,0,w ,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, (float)w/(float)h, 1.5, 10);
    gluLookAt(1.5, 2.5, 4, 
              0, 0.6, 0, 
              0, 1, 0); //Orient the camera
    glRotatef(5, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    initView(argc,argv);
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: just a guess, but maybe try adding `Sleep(1)` in your `draw` function

Comment: That actually worked! Do you know the technical reason for this working and why I need it while my fellow students don't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution:**

It seems that the simple solution using `Sleep(1)` in the render function worked. You've also asked why - I'm not sure I will be able to solve this properly, but here's my best guess:

**Why does it even work?**

Your fellow students can have VSync turned on by default in their drivers. This causes their code to run only as fast as the screen can refresh, most probably 60 fps. It gives you around 16 miliseconds to render the frame, and if the code is efficient (taking, say, 2 ms for render) it leaves plenty of time for the CPU to do other OS-related stuff, such as moving your window.

Now, if you disable vertical sync, the program will try to render as many frames as possible, effectively clogging all other processes. I've suggested you to use Sleep, because it reveals this one particular issue. It doesn't really matter if it's 1 or 3 ms, what it really does is say "hey, CPU, I'm not doing anything in particular right now, so you may do other things".

**But isn't it slowing my program?**

Using Sleep is a common technique. If you're concerned with that lost 1 ms every frame, you can also try putting `Sleep(0)`, as it should act exactly the same - giving the spare time to the CPU. You could also try enabling vertical sync and verifying if indeed my guess was correct.

As a side note, you can also look at CPU usage graphs with and without sleep. It should be 100% (or 50% on a dual-core CPU) without (running as fast as possible), and much lower with, depending on your program requirements and your CPU's speed.

**Additional remarks about Sleep(0)**

*After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.* - it's from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also note that on Linux systems behavior might be slightly different; but I'm not a linux expert; perhaps a passer-by could clarify.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation. Sleep(0) _yields_ the thread execution, making for partially 'cooperative' thread scheduling (a.o.t. _preemptive_ thread scheduling).

Comment: Regarding Linux. The function to relinquish CPU time on POSIX is `sched_yield`. It takes no parameters and has about the same effect as calling `Sleep(0)` on Windows.